# Python multiple regular expression replace

Tags: python, regex, replace

I'm a python newbie.
I've been searching days long, but found only some little bits of my conception.
Python 2.7 on windows (I chose python because it's multiplatform and result can be portable on windows).

I'd like to make a script, that searches a folder for *.txt UTF-8 text files, loads the content (one file after each other), changes non-ascii chars to html entitites, next adds html tags at the start and at the end of each line, but 2 variations of tags, one for the head of the file, and one for the tail of the file, which (head-tail) are separated by an empty line. After that, all the result have to be written out to another text file(s), like *.htm. To be visual:

unicode1.txt:

```
űnícődé text line1
űnícődé text line2
[empty line]
űnícődé text line3
űnícődé text line4
```

result have to be in unicode1.htm:

```
<p class='aaa'>&#369;n&iacute;c&#337;d&eacute; text line1</p>
<p class='aaa'>&#369;n&iacute;c&#337;d&eacute; text line2</p>
[empty line]
<p class='bbb'>&#369;n&iacute;c&#337;d&eacute; text line3</p>
<p class='bbb'>&#369;n&iacute;c&#337;d&eacute; text line3</p>
```

I started to develop the core of my solution, but I stucked. See script versions (for simplicity I chose encode with xmlcharrefreplace).

V1:

```
import re, cgi, fileinput
file="_utf8.txt"
text=""
for line in fileinput.input(file, inplace=0):
  line=cgi.escape(line.decode('utf8'),1).encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
  line=re.sub(r"^", "<p>", line, 1)
  text=text+re.sub(r"$", "</p>", line, 1)
print text
```

It worked, good result, but for this task fileinput is not a usable way I think.

V2:

```
import re, cgi, codecs
file="_utf8.txt"
text=""
f=codecs.open(file, encoding='utf-8')
for line in f:
  line=cgi.escape(line,1).encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
  line=re.sub(r"^", "<p>", line, 1)
  text=text+re.sub(r"$", "</p>", line, 1)
f.close()
print text
```

It messed up the result, closing tag at line start replacing first letter, etc.

V3 (tried multiline flag):

```
import re, cgi, codecs
file="_utf8.txt"
text=""
f=codecs.open(file, encoding='utf-8')
for line in f:
  line=cgi.escape(line,1).encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
  line=re.sub(r"^", "<p>", line, 1, flags=re.M)
  text=text+re.sub(r"$", "</p>", line, 1, flags=re.M)
f.close()
print text
```

Same result.

V4 (tried 1 regex instead of 2):

```
import re, cgi, codecs
file="_utf8.txt"
text=""
f=codecs.open(file, encoding='utf-8')
for line in f:
  line=cgi.escape(line,1).encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
  text=text+re.sub(r"^(.*)$", r"<p>\1</p>", line, 1)
f.close()
print text
```

Same result. Please help.

Edit: I just checked the result file with a hexeditor, and there is an x0D byte *before* each closing tag! Why?

Edit2: changes for a more logical approach

```
text+=re.sub(r"^(.*)$", r"<p>\1</p>", line, 1)
```

Edit3: with a hexeditor I saw what was the reason for the messed up result: extra CR (x0D) byte before each CRLF.
I tracked down the CR problem, what made that: the concatenation with +

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
text=""
f=u"unicode text line1\r\n unicode text line2"
for line in f:
  text+=line
print text
```

This results in:

```
unicode text line1\r\r\n unicode text line2
```

Any idea, how to fix this?

Comment: Indenting 4 spaces creates a code block.  Edit your question so that it is more readable.

Comment: I used indenting for the first time, but missed the empty paragraph before each indented block.

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand your question, I've tried your last script and it seems to get the result you are looking for and the result looks OK in the browser. Can you show the results of your testing with notes where the result is wrong?

Comment: @snim2 For me it messed up the result: closing tag at the line start, deleting the first letter, nothing at the line end. I try here a line to show the result if source line is 'text': </p>ext

Comment: This is the last line I got with your test data: "<p>&#369;n&#237;c&#337;d&#233; text line4</p>"

Comment: @snim2 Interesting... I got this with python2.7-windows: "</p>#369;n&#237;c&#337;d&#233; text line4"

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.2+ on Ubuntu 11.11. I'm surprised that there's a difference between platforms, maybe worth checking http://bugs.python.org/

Comment: Regexp for just adding some `<p> </p>` to begin and end of line is overkill, you can just save each line as `'<p>%s</p>' % line`. If you don't want to save empty lines, just test for `if not line.strip(): continue`

Comment: Why do you need line=re.sub(r"^", "<p>", line, 1)
  text=text+re.sub(r"$", "</p>", line, 1)? Can't you just do concatenation: text += "\n<p>" + line + "</p>"

Comment: @snim2 Ah, I just checked the result file with a hexeditor, and there is an x0D byte _before_ each closing tag! Why?

Comment: @Tib I can't see one with `cat -A`?

Comment: @Tib it's Carriage return. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: @reclosedev I know, I have the whole ascii code set in my brain (I was asm developer long time ago) so that's why I'm wondering.

Comment: @snim2 Sorry, on windows there is no 'cat' command (I have only a grep.exe and sed.exe)

Comment: @Tib does `type` do the same thing? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60244/is-there-replacement-for-cat-on-windows

Comment: @reclosedev I tried `'<p>%s</p>' % line` but the result is almost the same, there are x0Dx0Dx0A bytes before closing tag (CR+CR+LF).

Comment: @Tib: `'\r\n'` is a newline on Windows. You could strip it from the `line` before adding `<p>`,`</p>`

Comment: @snim2 `type` shows what i wrote first. `</p>#369;n&#237;c&#337;d&#233; text line4`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian But I need newlines, I don't want to strip it. This extra x0D what I don't need.

Comment: @Tib: bytes `\x0D\x0A` are the newline on Windows. Why do you need a newline *before* `</p>`?

Comment: @reclosedev Anyway I'm not familiar with python (as a newbie) so I don't understand waht this code makes: `'<p>%s</p>' % line`. I think %s gets the whole line from somewhere, but how, and then?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I know what is a newline. OK, I need not before, but after the tag. But before the tag, there is no full CRLF newline, only a CR.

Comment: `%s` used fro string formating in Python. More info in [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) But in Python 3.0+ it's deprecated and replaced with [.format](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings) like in  Rob Wouters answer.

Comment: @reclosedev thank you, it resembles a little bit (for me) Bash printf, is it?

Comment: @reclosedev: "deprecated" is a strong word. `.format()` is preferred to the `%` in Python3, but `%` doesn't go anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgi
import fileinput
import os
import shutil
import sys

def textfiles(rootdir, extensions=('.txt',)):
    for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for f in files:
            if f.lower().endswith(extensions):
               yield os.path.join(dirpath, f)

def htmlfiles(files):
    for f in files:
        root, _ = os.path.splitext(f)
        newf = root + '.html'
        shutil.copy2(f, newf)
        yield newf

for line in fileinput.input(htmlfiles(textfiles(sys.argv[1])), inplace=True):
    if fileinput.isfirstline():
       klass = 'aaa' # start head part
    line = cgi.escape(line.decode('utf-8').strip())
    line = line.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
    if not line: # empty line
       klass = 'bbb' # start tail part
       print(line)
    else:
       print('<p class="%s">%s</p>' % (klass, line))
```

#### [Example](http://ideone.com/Bfu8k)

```
$ python txt2html.py c:\root\dir
```

Comment: Added `import sys`. Now works, but only prints lines out, and I'd like it written out to *.htm text file(s). Is there a `fileoutput` also like `fileinput`?

Comment: @Tib: there are multiple options e.g., you could wrap `textfiles()` to copy each `'.txt'` file with `shutil.copy2()` and then yield `'.html'` filenames to fileinput (use `inplace=True` in this case). Or close/open new file inside `if fileinput.isfirstline()`.

Comment: I have to investigate and learn the docs because I did not understand totally what you wrote :-) Remember, I just started with python :-)

Comment: @Tib: I've added `htmlfiles()` function to illustrate the previous comment. Note: the data is read/written twice in this case.

Comment: @JF: Thanks, it works, I accept it as a solution. But what do you mean "data is read/written twice"? Once read, and once write, or else?

Comment: @Tib: `shutil.copy` reads `.txt` file, writes `.html` file; `fileinput.input()` reads `.html`, writes `.html`: 4 times in total.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for regular expressions at all here, just do this:

```
with open('utf8.txt') as f:
    class_name = 'aaa'
    for line in f:
        if line == '\n':
            classname = 'bbb'
        else:
            # decode / convert line
            line = '<p class="{0}">{1}</p>\n'.format(class_name, line.rstrip())
        # write line to file
```

The results you are getting do not look to be caused by the regular expressions as they appear to be correct. The problem is most likely in the line where you do your encoding / converting. Print that line without adding the tags to see if it is as expected.

Comment: it will leave newline before `</p>`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, nice catch. Added `rstrip` to the answer.

Comment: `.rstrip('\n\r')` will preserve `' \t'` at EOL.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, I thought about that but trailing whitespace in a `<p>` didn't seem very useful. If OP still wants to your suggestion should do it.

Comment: @Rob I made with `'<p>{0}</p>'.format(line)` but `with codecs.open(file, encoding='utf-8') as f:` and the result is: CR+CR+LF before closing tag `</p>`. Strange, because I see it in one string as `'<p>{0}</p>'`

Comment: @Tib, did you use my original method without rstrip? If so, try my edited answer with rstrip()

Comment: @RobWouters It works with rstrip, examined with hexeditor, thanks. (Is `.format` works for python2.7 the same way as python3?) But how to do with 2 types of tag: line1-2 `<p class='aaa'>` and line4-5 with `<p class='bbb'>`?

Comment: @Tib, there might be some differences but they won't matter here. I've edited the answer.

Comment: @RobWouters Not working, there is some catch with the `if`, because every line has `<p class="aaa">`. Indentation checked, your typo (classname/class_name) corrected.

Comment: @RobWouters: I don't understand why the "if" line doesn't find the empty line... I used `f=codecs.open(file, encoding='utf-8')` instead of `with open('utf8.txt') as f:`

Comment: @Tib, it's possible the line contains spaces. You could try `if not line.strip():`

Comment: @RobWouters Thanks, with `strip()` that worked on the `if` condition, writes `class=bbb` but the empty line disappered from the result... Possibly not the concatenation, but the `for line in f:` adds the extra x0D byte to the `line` variable?

Comment: @RobWouters: I tested my question. No, not the `for` adds extra byte. But there is no space in the `line` variable while the `if` testing it... Interesting. Anyway I added before `else` the following: `text+="\n"` and now it's fully working. You may add this to your sourcecode.

Comment: @Gandaro: if you edited last time the answer-source: `if line=="\n":` not working, but `if line=="\r\n":` works (but no empty line).

Comment: @Tib Well I am using a Unix-like system which uses '\n' for line breaks.