# cat command for windows

Tags: windows, linux, cat

I have 4 files

```
sitefiles.tar.gz.splitaa
sitefiles.tar.gz.splitab
sitefiles.tar.gz.splitac
sitefiles.tar.gz.splitad
```

I need a command or program that works like "cat" on linux. that way I can join all the 4 files into 1 file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there replacement for cat on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60244/is-there-replacement-for-cat-on-windows)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Windows Powershell supports `cat`.

However you can do it even simpler, using a normal console:

```
copy /b sitefiles.tar.gz.split* sitefiles.tar.gz
```

This will append all files into `sitefiles.tar.gz`.

If you want to join specific files, or if you want to append them in a specific order (default is sorting the filenames alphabetical) append them using `+`:

```
copy /b sitefiles.tar.gz.splitaa+sitefiles.tar.gz.splitab+sitefiles.tar.gz.splitac+sitefiles.tar.gz.splitad sitefiles.tar.gz
```