# Execute multi-line python code inside Windows Batch script

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, scripting

**I want to use multiline python statements inside Windows Batch script.**

For example, my BAT script is:

```sh
@echo off
echo "Executing Python Code..."
goto python_code

:python_code_back
echo "Executed Python Code!"

pause
exit()

:python_code
python -c print("""Python code running""")
goto python_code_back
```

`python -c` works fine for single statements. But let my python code be embedded is:

```py
import random
num = input("Enter Number: ")
num = int(num)
if num%2 == 0:
  print("Even")
else:
  print("Odd")
  
exit()
```

**How do I embed this *Python code* into my *Windows Batch Script* without calling another python script or making temporary python files?**

I have some options that I have gone through:

1. Use `python -c` with semicolons: How do I intend the code like if
   statements above? If there are ways, one might still want clean code
   in multiple lines but I would appreciate the answer for this.
2. Can I just run `python` and find a way to send commands to the interpreter? Maybe using subprocesses?
3. Is there any way I can build a multi-line string that has the python code and then send it to the python interpreter or python command?
4. In bash we could use EOF to keep multi-lines clean. Is there any similar method [to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17467441/how-to-embed-python-code-in-batch-script) in BAT? I think no because people have proposed [many workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17467441/how-to-embed-python-code-in-batch-script) to this.
5. Can `'''` (three single-quotes) or `"""` (three douuble-quotes) syntax be used that are specially interpreted by Batch? Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41642012/how-to-insert-python-code-in-a-bat-file)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

```
0<0# : ^
''' 
@echo off
echo batch code
python %~f0 %* 
exit /b 0
'''

import random
import sys



def isOdd():
    print("python code")
    num = input("Enter Number: ")
    num = int(num)
    if num%2 == 0:
      print("Even")
    else:
      print("Odd")

def printScriptName():
    print(sys.modules['__main__'].__file__)
    
eval(sys.argv[1] + '()')
exit()
```

Example usage:

```
call pythonEmbeddedInBatch.bat isOdd
call pythonEmbeddedInBatch.bat printScriptName
```

The first line will be boolean expression in python ,but a redirection to an empty label in batch. The rest of the batch code will be within multiline python comment.

Answer (score -1):

Use this simple python gui to convert all py scripts in folder to bat files :

```
0<0# : ^
''' 
@echo off
set script=%~f0
python -x "%script%" %*
exit /b 0/b 0
'''

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

def browse_folder():
    foldername = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir=input_entry.get())
    input_entry.delete(0, END)
    input_entry.insert(0, foldername)

def convert_files():
    input_path = input_entry.get()
    if os.path.isdir(input_path):
        # Input path is a directory, so convert all Python files in the directory
        for filename in os.listdir(input_path):
            if filename.endswith(".py"):
                convert_single_file(os.path.join(input_path, filename))

def convert_single_file(filename):
    if filename:
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            content = f.read()
        # Add the batch file code at the beginning of the file
        content = '0<0# : ^\n\'\'\' \n@echo off\nset script=%~f0\npython -x "%script%" %*\nexit /b 0\n\'\'\'\n' + content
        # Get the base name of the original file
        base_name, _ = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))
        # Save the modified content as a batch file
        with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(filename), f"{base_name}.bat"), 'w') as f:
            f.write(content)

root = Tk()
root.title("Python to Batch Converter")

# Scale the GUI by a factor of 4
root.tk.call('tk', 'scaling', 4.0)

input_label = Label(root, text="Input folder:")
input_label.pack()

input_entry = Entry(root)
input_entry.pack()

browse_folder_button = Button(root, text="Browse Folder", command=browse_folder)
browse_folder_button.pack()

convert_button = Button(root, text="CONVERT", command=convert_files)
convert_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).