# "load data infile" with many files

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I have to load and append data to a MySQL table from many files. The files are stored in the same directory.

To load data from a single file I use:

```
load data local infile 'D:\\MyDir\\file.DAT' into table catasto.dm_import fields terminated by '|' lines terminated by '\n';
```

Now I need to append every file contained in the directory `D:\MyDir` into table `dm_import`.
How can I do this? I work with MySQL Workbench and Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off some tips in this thread:

[Is there replacement for cat on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60244/is-there-replacement-for-cat-on-windows)

```
cd D:\MyDir;
copy /b *.DAT _all.DAT;
load data local infile '_all.DAT' into table catasto.dm_import fields terminated by '|' lines terminated by '\n';
del _all.DAT;
```

That should get you what you're after without any python required.

What copy /b is doing is essentially taking all the files in the directory, joining them up end to end and then saving the output in _all.DAT

It's a good idea to delete _all.DAT after you're finished or you could end up in a situation where you keep joining _all.DAT on to the end of _all.DAT in addition to all the .DAT files in the directory...messy!

Answer (score 0):

try to merge your files first into one file. the execute the load data command. you can use windows command copy /b *.dat newfile then load data local infile newfile.