# Unix 'Cat' equivalent command in Windows cmd

Tags: unix, cmd

I have being trying to write some scripts in both unix and windows environment. I am facing problem when trying to write equivalent windows command for:

```
cmd = "cat raw_data.txt | awk -F\"}\" '{for(i =1; i<=NF-1; i++){print $i\"}\"}}' | sed 's/^,//' | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' | sed 's/^{//; s/}$//'"
```

Comment: stop using `cat` when you don't need to. `awk '....' raw_data.txt | sed ...` Also, what is your intent with `cmd = "cat ...` Just to initialize a variable with the string literal `cat raw_...` ? OR to assign the output of the that command chain to the variable `cmd`? I'll be surprized if others can show you a way to achieve a common syntax between Windows and Unix, unless you're using a Unix on Windows platform, like cygwin, mingw or Uwin. Good luck.

Comment: Hey @shellter I am sorry but I didn't get all of what you asked me there! But, I am trying to convert a python program developed in Linux environment to Windows environment and was lost when it came to this particular point.

Comment: if you're " trying to convert a python program developed in Linux environment to Windows environment", then you should include that information in your question and probably include a python tag as well. BUT, as is, your question is to vague to be answerable. You need to reduce the problem to so that others can help solve it. right now there are too many unknowables about your problem and situation. Good luck.

Comment: As a standard windows environment doesn't have `awk` (or many other unix tools available), you might search for "convert unix script to powershell". Good luck.

Comment: There's a similar SO question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60244/is-there-replacement-for-cat-on-windows).

Answer (score 5):

```
type file1 >> file2
as 
cat file1 file2 > file3
```

type is the one used equivalent to cat command but it can have only part of its functionality

Answer (score 0):

You can use copy /b like this:

```
copy /b file1+file2 newfile
```