# Windows equivalent for cat command to ingest data into ElasticSearch using Logstash

Tags: windows, elasticsearch, command-line, logstash

I'm trying to run the [ELK for NGINX Plus (JSON) example](https://github.com/elastic/examples/tree/master/ELK_NGINX_Plus-json) on a Windows 10 machine, and am hung up on finding a Windows equivalent to the following unix command for ingesting the log data into Elasticsearch:

```
cat nginxplus_json_logs | <path_to_logstash_root_dir>/bin/logstash -f nginxplus_json_logstash.conf
```

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058247/unix-cat-equivalent-command-in-windows-cmd) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60244/is-there-replacement-for-cat-on-windows) I understand that `type` can perform some of the same actions as `cat` in unix.  I tried the exact same command replacing `cat` with `type`, which unsurprisingly didn't work. Here is my command and response:

```
type nginxplus_json_logs.txt | ../logstash-2.1.1/bin/logstash -f nginxplus_json_logstash.conf

'..' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Is it possible to replicate that action using the `type` command? If so, how do I need to change the way I have my command formatted?

Comment: If possible, install msys2, it has cat and other Linux utilities

Comment: I'm able to run the cat command from msys2, but now it looks like there's an issue with my configuration file.  Here's the error message I'm getting:    "Error: The setting `host` in plugin `elasticsearch` is obsolete and is no longer available.  Please use the 'hosts' setting instead"

Comment: Update: I changed `host` to `hosts` in nginxplus_json_logstash.conf and am now getting an error message about other settings: `{:timestamp=>"2016-02-12T11:40:56.719000-0800", :message=>"Unknown setting 'protocol' for elasticsearch", :level=>:error}
{:timestamp=>"2016-02-12T11:40:56.722000-0800", :message=>"Unknown setting 'cluster' for elasticsearch", :level=>:error}
Error: Something is wrong with your configuration.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows your command should be using backslashes "\" instead of forward slashes "/" and you need to call the `logstash.bat` file instead of `logstash`.

So your command must look like this instead (make sure to `cd` into the right folder first):

```
type nginxplus_json_logs.txt | ..\logstash-2.1.1\bin\logstash.bat -f nginxplus_json_logstash.conf
```

Furthermore, the logstash configuration file you have is for Logstash 1.5.4, since you have 2.1.1, you can modify your `elasticsearch` output to look like this instead:

```
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "nginxplus_json_elk_example"
    document_type => "logs"
    template => "./nginxplus_json_template.json"
    template_name => "nginxplus_json_elk_example"
    template_overwrite => true
  }
```