# How to source multiple functions in psql?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a directory with at least 6 function files.

I'm using psql and I need to be able to source (*initialize* ?) all function files at once.

I'm sure making a single function and call all others like `SELECT fn1, fn2` isn't going to work.

Doing `\i functions_folder/fn1.sql` 6 times isn't ideal either.

So is there a way I can (maybe) `\i functions/*.sql`? Doing that currently gives me

`functions/*.sql: No such file or directory`

I'm using psql on postgresql 9.6.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using *nix OS:

```
postgres=# \! cat ./functions/*.sql > all_functions.sql
postgres=# \i all_functions.sql
```

For Windows try to find the analogue of the `cat` (as I remember it is `copy` command with some flags)

PS I have the feeling that it could be done by using backquotes:

> Within an argument, text that is enclosed in backquotes (`) is taken as a command line that is passed to the shell. The output of the command (with any trailing newline removed) replaces the backquoted text.

[Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS)

But still have no idea how. Probably somebody more experienced will provide a hint...

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Linux and this worked perfectly. No backquotes/backticks. Also it's `type` command not cat see [Windows Alternative to cat command](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60254/2405689)

Comment: @ArchNoob You provided the link to exactly that question where I found info about the Windows alternative for POSIX `cat` :o) Look at the comments for the accepted answer (about unnecessary lines) and to the next answer with `copy /b`. Good luck.

Comment: It surely is quite a thread to read but yeah I've seen the problems with `type` in it. Thanks for correction and the good luck man.

Answer (score 2):

Create a wrapper that contains the `\i` commands, and `\i` the wrapper.

Comment: "wrapper that contains the` \i` commands" you mean the wrapper that contains the functions filenames? Or contains `\i filename.sql \n \i filaname2.sql` ?

Comment: The latter; use a file that includes other files.

Comment: Oh, kinda like what Abelisto said in his answer? `cat` ing the contents of the function files. I wouldn't have known that trick. Thanks. :D

Comment: @ArchNoob Yes, it is yet another alternative: `ls ./functions/*.sql | sed -e 's/^/\\i /g' > wrapper.sql` But we are talking not about PostgreSQL but about shell :o)

Comment: Sure, I could tell. Someone in irc (ningu) got me to something like `cat ./functions/* | psql ...` but I wanted something more psql-*ish* .. @Abelisto ;)