# How to pipe multiple sql- and py-scripts

Tags: python, pipeline, windows-shell

I have the following code copied from [github gtfs_SQL_importer](https://github.com/cbick/gtfs_SQL_importer):

```
cat gtfs_tables.sql \
  <(python import_gtfs_to_sql.py path/to/gtfs/data/directory) \
  gtfs_tables_makeindexes.sql \
  vacuumer.sql \
  | psql mydbname
```

I tried to run this on windows and replaced the call to the UNIX-command `cat` by the windows equivalent `type` which should work similar as of [is-there-replacement-for-cat-on-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60244/is-there-replacement-for-cat-on-windows).

However when I execute that code I get some error:

> The syntax for the filename, directory or filesystem is wrong.

So I tried to limit the number of piped files to only combine the call to python and the call to `psql`:

```
type <(C:/python27/python path/to/py-script.py path/to/file-argument) | psql -U myUser -d myDatabase
```

which results in the same error.

However when I execute the python-script alone it works as expected:

```
C:/python27/python path/to/py-script.py path/to/file-argument
```

So I assume the error results from using `type` in order to pipe the result of the script directly to `psql`.

Does anyone know the correct syntax?

EDIT: To ensure the problem is not related to a file not being found I used absolute paths for all arguments within my command except the `type` and the `psql`-command (which are both handled via the `%PATH%`-variable).

Comment: Are you sure that your syntax is correct? You have a redirection operator directly after `type`. Could you try to do: `type gtfs_tables.sql <(C:/python27/python path/tp/py-script.py path/to/file-argument) | psql -U myUser -d myDataBase`?

Comment: as of http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true the `<`-command should read data from my python-script and send it to the pipe (in my case to `psql`). However I also added the first sql-file before the `<` which yields to the same message.

Comment: What is the output of just this part `type <(C:/python27/python path/to/py-script.py path/to/file-argument)`?

Comment: As I remember, <() operator is bash-specific, not even POSIX-specific. It will hardly work on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Comment**: So I can´t combine the sql-files and the output from my pythonscript together and pipe them to psql?

Another approach, create your own `cat` with Python,
or add the first three line of code to `import_gtfs_to_sql.py`,
for instance:

```
# Usage
python import_gtfs_to_sql.py... | python myCat.py gtfs_tables.sql | psql mydbname

#myCat.py
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as fh:
    sys.stdout.write(fh.read())

sys.stdout.write(sys.stdin.read())
```

---

**Comment**: I already know the error comes from type<(python...)

`TYPE` command does not accept `stdin`.

Therefore your only solution is Option 2.

Another approach is to use your Python Script to do `print gtfs_tables.sql`.

**Question**: ***the syntax for the filename, directory or filesystem is wrong***.

1. Find out from which part the above Error comes from.

   ```
    a) type gtfs_tables.sql
    b) type <(python ...   
    c) type gtfs_tables.sql <(python ...  
    d) type gtfs_tables.sql | psql mydbname
    e) type <(python ... | psql mydbname
   ```
2. Save the Output of `<(python ...`   to a File and try

   ```
    python ... > tmp_python_output
    type gtfs_tables.sql tmp_python_output | psql mydbname
   ```

Comment: I allready know the error comes from `type<(python...)`. Thus your answer doesn´t solve the problem at all.

Comment: "TYPE command does not accept stdin." So I can´t combine the sql-files and the output from my pythonscript together and pipe them to psql? Sad, but thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 4):

Install [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) and use unix cat on Windows.