# Command which copies stdin to stdout

Tags: windows, cmd

I'm updating the test suite of the standard library of the Crystal programming language to run on Windows. To test the spawning of new processes with pipes for stdout and stdin on unix, `cat` is used as a "dummy process" which copies stdin to stdout for testing.

What's the simplest command to achieve the same effect on windows using `cmd.exe` commands?

Comment: You can try with `find /v ""`

Comment: Or, if your tests don't send more than 65535 lines and the stdout of the process is also redirected (not the console), you can simply use `more`

Comment: @MCND `find /v ""` works well for me, could you send this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple command that can be found in all windows versions that can be used as an alternative to the linux `cat` command in the indicated scenario is

```
find /v ""
```

As is, it will read lines from standard input and write them to standard output.

note: While `more` and `findstr "^"` could, sometimes, be used, both have several limitations that make `find /v ""` a better alternative.

Comment: This gives me `FIND: Parameter format not correct`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
powershell.exe -c "[Console]::OpenStandardInput().CopyTo([Console]::OpenStandardOutput())"
```

The accepted solution of using (`find /v ""`) has some problems:

- It corrupts binary data. It tries to read the input as text with CRLF line endings. If you pass it data which doesn't contain a newline, it will output a CRLF at the end. It also fails if there is a line longer than its line limit (4091 characters)
- When given empty input, it returns an exit code of 1. By contrast, Unix `cat` will return an exit code of 0 when the input is empty. A test which tests the exit code and expects it to be zero will fail when the input is empty. A workaround is to do `find /v "" & :` (assuming you are running it from `cmd.exe`, such as by using `cmd.exe /c`) – but then, if the find actually fails to run for any reason (see next bullet point), you will not get a failure exit code to notify you
- On some systems, you may have MSYS/Cygwin/etc `find` in your path before Windows `find`. (Of course, in that case you probably have `cat` in your path too, and hence don't need to do this at all – but, you may be looking for a solution which you know will work even on systems without MSYS/Cygwin/etc installed.) Assuming you are running it using `cmd.exe /c`, you can solve this by using `%windir%\system32\find.exe /v ""`

I think this PowerShell oneliner is better in that it avoids the above problems.